# How to change position of the axes values of a Sage plot.

Tags: graphing-functions, sagemath, python

I am plotting 2D functions on Sage, and I would like to move the values displayed along the $y$ axis (the ticks) from the left of the axis to the rigth, because they bother me there. I had a look and I think this can be done in Python with `matplotlib` (using `set_tick_params()` or `set_ticks_position()`) which is included in Sage, but I am not sure of how to combine a `region_plot()` from Sage with this axis modification.

Comment: See also http://ask.sagemath.org/question/33387/how-to-change-position-of-the-axes-values-of-a-sage-plot/

Comment: (By the way, maybe this belongs more on stackoverflow itself; this isn't really a math question.)

Comment: Yes, I realized about it afterwards, sorry for that and thank you!